# Unity Facebook SDK: How to detect login in other devices?

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

How can I detect if a Facebook account login in other devices, using Facebook SDK for Unity? I need to invalidated something in old device when user change to new device.

Comment: Try 'FB.IsLoggedIn'.

Comment: Thank you. Does it means when you login FB in new device, the FB's state in old device become "FB.IsLoggedIn = false"?

Comment: You have to handle this on your own I suppose. Like on login you can save device Id in some server and then match those device Ids against the fb user id which should be saved on server too. And if you get true while comparing device ids, you can remove the AccessToken.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, then I need to consider another approach.

Comment: You can use Firebase or GameSparks to start as demo. Please mark answer as useful. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see anything like "Like" or "Upvote" button. How could I mark useful answer?

Comment: its Up button on the left of my comment. Thanks.

Comment: I actually don't see it. Or because it is a comment instead of a official answer?

Comment: Never mind. Glad to help :)